# Should I try to figure out geometric construction?

Tags: geometry

I've been reading and working through the book - Euclid and Beyond by Robin Hartshorne. In the first chapter there are a few constructions that I haven't been taught in school (just finished 11th Grade). How should I approach them? Should I try to figure out them myself or instead check it online, get and intuition for it and go ahead?

Comment: Any question that involves "should" requires an explanation of what your goals are.

Comment: I want to better my understanding of geometry, try to do some stuff that I haven't been taught in school which seems interesting and develop some intuition for geometry so it isn't just some string of "algorithms" to find an angle or side. I hope this helps.

Comment: Always try to figure things out yourself first. Can't go wrong. If you do this and get stuck, then come back here and post and we can help ; )

Comment: If you want to "develop some intuition for geometry" than you definitely need to try to figure them out yourself. For example, when I was in high school I read about trigonometry, but I did not develop an intuition for it until I took a class and had to do exercises. I learned my lesson, and now do problems that I don't have to do--to develop my own intuition.